# How to use google analytics for wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have created a plugin and would like to use statistics, google-analytics preferably. Is there a way of doing so?

I've googled hard but couldn't find a solution so far

Comment: Note that if you're planning to distribute your plugin on the WordPress repository, the Plugins team may reject it / take it down from the directory as "[Plugins may not track users without their consent](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/#7-plugins-may-not-track-users-without-their-consent)."

Comment: I have created settings page with checkbox and explanation for the user of why I am doing this.

Comment: In that case you're good to go :) Regarding your question, GA has tools you can use to track actions (clicks, for example). Have you checked [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) yet?

Comment: Well, I was looking for something like this. Just thought there's some wordpress specific way or tutorial. Thanks, anyways.

Comment: WordPress is just a PHP framework. You don't really need to do anything specific to make GA work with WP.